# Ninject with Ria Services (Custom DomainService)

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, ninject, wcf-ria-services

I have a situation where I am accessing repositories within my custom Domain Services and I'd prefer to have them injected.

I.e.

```
    [EnableClientAccess()]
    public class UserDomainService : DomainService
    {

    public IUserRepository repo;

    public UserDomainService(IUserRepository userRepo)
        : base()
    {
       repo = userRepo;            
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return this.repo.GetUsers();
    }
```

I have numerous Domain Services and what I'm unsure of is where to define a Ninject module to hold my type bindings for all of my Domain Services and load it into the kernel.  I am looking for a simple example to demonstrate how I might do this.

Comment: I haven't seen any, but I'd be interested if you find one. For now, you should be able to create a custom DomainServiceFactory that uses Ninject.

Comment: @Kyle McClellan - one option I did think of was to extend the NinjectHttpApplication class and define the bindings and module in the Global.asax.  However, I think I lack a good understanding of how/where these DomainServices operate under.  The Global.asax code ran fine, but IUserRepository within the custom Domain Service was still NULL when the above code ran.  I guess that tells me they are not operating under the same context?  I think I may take your approach and go with the factory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on the right tracking with Ninject.Extensions.Web - extending the NinjectHttpApplication in place of the default Global.asax.

However, it does not work because it does *not* expose the KernelContainer (access to your newly defined Ninject module) such that you are not able inject your custom domain service like you would with the page base class it provides.

So...

I ended up created a similar class extending HttpApplication that publicly exposes the static kernel.  Then, I created a base domain service that all of my domain services inherit from.  Within the constructor, I then make a call to inject my domain service instance:

```
    [EnableClientAccess()]
    public class BaseDomainService : DomainService
    {
        public BaseDomainService()
           : base()
        {
            MyCustomStaticKernelContainer.Inject(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why didn't you use the DomainService.Factory? The CreateDomainService method of IDomainServiceFactory (the return type of DomainService.Factory) is how Ria Services the instance of DomainService internally, and is the recommended way for users to hook into the creation process. Good answer on Stack overflow here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294331/net-ria-services-domainservice-needs-a-parameterless-constructor. Good example of using DomainServices.Factory with AutoFac container here: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/RIAServices